# Grunt watch task does not update Spring Boot project

Tags: spring-boot, gruntjs

I am building a simple webapp using `spring-boot` for the server, and an `AngularJS` client.

I was able to create the client app under `src > main > resources > static`, and when I build it and restart the app, the result is updated.

I am trying to configure my project to work with `grunt watch`. Currently the watch task refreshed my page, but does not update the result.

pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.5.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Application.java:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan("com.example.ws")
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
    @Override
    public SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(Application.class);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

Configuration class:

```
 @Configuration
    public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/resources/static/app/build");
        registry.addResourceHandler("/**.css").addResourceLocations("classpath:/resources/static/app/build");
        registry.addResourceHandler("/**.js").addResourceLocations("classpath:/resources/static/app/build");

    }
}
```

Comment: Take a look into JHipster - http://jhipster.github.io/

Comment: I did, but I would like to do the same with existing projects later...